# Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста как решить вот такую задачу при помощи рекурсии:

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить вот такую задачу при помощи рекурсии:
Сделайте функцию inArray('hello', ['helloo', hello', 'hihi']), которая определяет,
есть в массиве элемент с заданным текстом или нет.
Функция первым параметром должна принимать текст элемента, а вторым - массив, в котором ищем.
Функция должна вернуть true или false.
вам поможет метод splice)

```
function inArray(str,mass){
    for (let i = 0; i <= mass.length - 1; i ++){
        if(str !== mass[i]){
            mass.splice(0,1);
            inArray(str,mass);
        }
        else return true;
    }
}

console.log(inArray('hello', ['helloo', 'hello', 'hihi']));
```

Comment: А Вы пробовали решать данную задачу сами? Приложите пожалуйста к вопросу свой вариант решения данной проблемы.

Comment: А зачем тут splice и рекурсия?

Comment: Весть смысл в том чтобы эту задачу сделать рекурсией, циклом да ее можно сделать проще,но тут именно такие условия)

Comment: вместо `splice(0,1)` логично использовать `shift()` или `pop`: `function contains(str, arr) { return arr.length && ((arr.shift() === str) || contains(str, arr));}` Никакой `for` или `splice` тут не нужен

Answer (score 1):

Вам осталось добавить return для рекурсивного вызова и return на тот случай, если все элементы перебраны и ничего не нашлось (то есть — функция получила пустой массив и цикл не был запущен):

```js
function inArray(str, mass){
    for (let i = 0; i <= mass.length - 1; i++){
        if(str !== mass[i]){
            mass.splice(0, 1);
            return inArray(str, mass);
        }
        else return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(inArray('helloo', ['helloo', 'hello', 'hihi']));
console.log(inArray('hello', ['helloo', 'hello', 'hihi']));
console.log(inArray('hihi', ['helloo', 'hello', 'hihi']));
console.log(inArray('42', ['helloo', 'hello', 'hihi']));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш ответ!, теперь все стало на свои места, сутки сидел не мог сделать)

Answer (score 1):

```
function inArray(str, arr) {
    if ( arr.length === 0 ) 
        return false;
    if ( arr[0] !== str ) {
        return inArray( str, arr.splice(1,arr.length - 1) ); 
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]